# Deploy Account Hierarchy Columns Metadata

Tags: deployment, account, metadata

Is there any way to deploy Account hierarchy Columns through Metadata? So far I was unable to find the corresponding metadata in the documentation and also going through the Org Metadata with the VSCode OrgBrowser.
What would be the way to go? Is it a manual deployment action to setup Account Hierarchy Columns on the Orgs?

Comment: Are you referring to the standard field `ParentId` field on `Account` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, assuming you understand how to configure the package.xml to include

```
<types>
    ...
    <members>Account.Org_Account_Hierarchy</members>
    ...
    <name>ListView</name>
</types>
```

a resulting file in the `objects` (Account) folder after source org retrieval will give you the definition of a configured Hierarchy Column. Here is mine:

```
<listViews>
    <fullName>Org_Account_Hierarchy</fullName>
    <columns>AccContact__c</columns>
    <columns>ACCOUNT.NAME</columns>
    <columns>ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER</columns>
    <columns>CORE.USERS.ALIAS</columns>
    <columns>ACCOUNT.SITE</columns>
    <columns>ACCOUNT_SOURCE</columns>
    <columns>Active__c</columns>
    <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
    <label>Org_Account_Hierarchy</label>
</listViews>
```

Now you can use Workbench or a tool of your choice to deploy the definition into a target org and/or store in source control.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the hint I needed! Didn't know this is handled as a List view.

Comment: For anybody wondering- the relative path for this standard list view is-

```force-app/main/default/objects/Account/listViews/Org_Account_Hierarchy.listView-meta.xml```